# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) on tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash

I've turned on NSZombieEnabled, and I seem to be getting a crash when the following happens.

Go to the "Settings" view controller via a tabbar and go into the culprit view controller from there, then click on another tab (without going back to the settings view controller before) and then click on the tabbar for "Settings" again.

This is the code for the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"temp"] autorelease];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

if(indexPath.section == 1 && [PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.cards != nil)
{
    if([[PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.cards count] > indexPath.row)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        //Reverse the array if it's in the wrong order
        if([[[[PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.cards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] cardStatus] isEqualToString:@"Secondary"] && indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            NSArray* reversedArray = [[[PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.cards reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
            [PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.cards = reversedArray;
        }

        PMCardInfo *cardInfo = [[PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.cards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([cardInfo.cardStatus isEqualToString:@"Primary"] && indexPath.row == 1)
            cardInfo = [[PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.cards objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row -1)];

        UILabel *cardLabel =
        [[[UILabel alloc]
          initWithFrame:
          CGRectMake(
                     cell.indentationWidth,
                     0.075 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                     200,
                     26)]
         autorelease];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cardLabel];
        cardLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cardInfo.cardStatus capitalizedString]];
        cardLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cardLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        cardLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];


        NSString *cardTypeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cardInfo.cardType capitalizedString]];

        CGSize cardTypeStringSize = [cardTypeString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]];

        UILabel *cardTypeLabel =
        [[[UILabel alloc]
          initWithFrame:
          CGRectMake(
                     cell.indentationWidth,
                     0.63 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                     cardTypeStringSize.width,
                     24)]
         autorelease];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cardTypeLabel];
        cardTypeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cardInfo.cardType capitalizedString]];
        cardTypeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cardTypeLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        cardTypeLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];

        UILabel *digitsLabel =
        [[[UILabel alloc]
          initWithFrame:
          CGRectMake(
                     cardTypeStringSize.width + 4 + cell.indentationWidth,
                     0.6 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                     150,
                     26)]
         autorelease];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:digitsLabel];
        digitsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ending with %@", cardInfo.last4Digits];
        digitsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        digitsLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        digitsLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];

        //Let's make the expiration year just two digits
        if(cardInfo.expYear.length == 4)
            cardInfo.expYear = [cardInfo.expYear substringFromIndex:2];

        UILabel *expirationLabel =
        [[[UILabel alloc]
          initWithFrame:
          CGRectMake(
                     cell.indentationWidth,
                     1.0 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                     150,
                     26)]
         autorelease];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:expirationLabel];
        expirationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expires on %@/%@", cardInfo.expMonth, cardInfo.expYear];
        expirationLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        expirationLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        expirationLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    }
    else 
    {
        UILabel *cardTypeLabel =
        [[[UILabel alloc]
          initWithFrame:
          CGRectMake(
                     cell.indentationWidth,
                     0.25 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                     275.0,
                     24)]
         autorelease];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cardTypeLabel];
        if([[PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.cards count] == 2)
            cardTypeLabel.text = @"Swap Primary and Secondary Cards";
        else
            cardTypeLabel.text = @"Add Credit Card";
        cardTypeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        cardTypeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cardTypeLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        cardTypeLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    }
}
else if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if([PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.wallet != nil)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            NSString *balanceString = [Util numberToCurrencyString:[PMSessionManager instance].paymentMethods.wallet.balance];
            NSString *availableBalanceString = @"Available Balance";

            CGSize balanceStringSize = [balanceString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:32.0]];
            CGSize availableBalanceStringSize = [availableBalanceString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]];

            CGFloat textWidth = balanceStringSize.width + 5.0 + availableBalanceStringSize.width;
            CGFloat margin = (275.0 - textWidth)/2;

            UILabel *balanceLabel =
            [[[UILabel alloc]
              initWithFrame:
              CGRectMake(
                         cell.indentationWidth + margin,
                         0.45 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                         275.0,
                         32)]
             autorelease];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:balanceLabel];
            balanceLabel.text = balanceString;
            balanceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            balanceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            balanceLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
            balanceLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:32.0];

            UILabel *walletBalanceLabel =
            [[[UILabel alloc]
              initWithFrame:
              CGRectMake(
                         balanceStringSize.width + 5 + cell.indentationWidth + margin,
                         0.72 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                         275.0,
                         24)]
             autorelease];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:walletBalanceLabel];
            walletBalanceLabel.text = availableBalanceString;
            walletBalanceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            walletBalanceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            walletBalanceLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
            walletBalanceLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
        if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            UILabel *walletSettingsLabel =
            [[[UILabel alloc]
              initWithFrame:
              CGRectMake(
                         cell.indentationWidth,
                         0.25 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                         275.0,
                         24)]
             autorelease];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:walletSettingsLabel];
            walletSettingsLabel.text = @"Edit Wallet Settings";
            walletSettingsLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            walletSettingsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            walletSettingsLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
            walletSettingsLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            UILabel *learnMoreLabel =
            [[[UILabel alloc]
              initWithFrame:
              CGRectMake(
                         cell.indentationWidth,
                         0.25 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                         275.0,
                         24)]
             autorelease];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:learnMoreLabel];
            learnMoreLabel.text = @"Learn More";
            learnMoreLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            learnMoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            learnMoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
            learnMoreLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
        }
        if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            UILabel *signUpLabel =
            [[[UILabel alloc]
              initWithFrame:
              CGRectMake(
                         cell.indentationWidth,
                         0.25 * (tableView.rowHeight - 2 * 14),
                         275.0,
                         24)]
             autorelease];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:signUpLabel];
            signUpLabel.text = @"Sign Up for Wallet";
            signUpLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            signUpLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            signUpLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
            signUpLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
        }
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

With NSZombieEnabled, I get this message in the logs:

```
-[PaymentMethodViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x404ae00
```

The above code snippet is from this PaymentMethodViewController. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer to this question seems to have fixed the issue.

[Pop to root view controller without animation crash for the table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499913/pop-to-root-view-controller-without-animation-crash-for-the-table-view)